# Initialize instance variables as key/value pair from NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, nsdictionary, nsobject, kvc

I have my NSObject subclass's public interface defined as,

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    NSString *_key1;
    NSString *_key2;
    NSString *_key3;
}
- (id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict;
@end
```

Is there are trick to implement the initWithDict: method so that I can pass a NSDictionary defined as

> {"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3"}

and the init method can set the  related instance variables with their corresponding "value"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use [KVC](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2FCocoa%2FConceptual%2FKeyValueCoding%2FArticles%2FKeyValueCoding.html&ei=cas3UMLuE4L_4QSnmoDwCQ&usg=AFQjCNFzXmy29jbiaowDZpHPhfDCPYPW9g&sig2=Vglw64w-z9O-tpruHyR1aA).

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key1" : @"value1", @"key2" : @"value2", @"key3" : @"value3"};
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
   [self setValue:dict[key] forKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DrummerB answer, if you have nested object like below,

```
@interface InnerObject : NSObject
{
    NSString *innerKey1;
}
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    NSString *key1;
    NSString *key2;
    NSString *key3;
    InnerObject *innerObj; 
}
```

You can set value to the iVar innerKey1 also by below method:

```
MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc]init];
obj.innerObj = [[InnerObject alloc]init];
[obj setValue:yourValue forKeyPath:innerObj.innerKey1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also initialize your instance variables/properties from a dictionary like this:

```
[self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictionary];
```

Here is the official Apple Documentation on setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValuesForKeysWithDictionary: